# Xcode 7.3 Autolayout Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode7, ios-autolayout

Ever since I switched to Xcode 7.3 my life has become a living hell as Xcode started showing autolayout constraint issues in my layouts which were working fine in Xcode 7.2 and even after searching a lot I couldn't find a solution. Here's the problem...

I am trying to create a dynamic sizing cell having an UIImageView of certain aspect ratio(6:5). Below the image is a 1px height UIView that show as a separator(I cannot use the default separator for some reason so this is a must). Here are the constraints.

[image: Here are the constraints]

I assume that with these constraints the height of the cell can be calculated dynamically whenever the cell is shown. This all is very simple and works as expected if built using Xcode 7.2 but Xcode 7.3 shows warning at runtime.

[image: Here]

Most of the time the views are shown perfectly but in few cases, because constraints are broken at runtime, views are laid out of their place. This is more of a general problem and is happening with almost all of my UITableViewCells. This particular example is the simplest of them all. Anyone with decent know how of autolayout cannot make a mistake in setting correct constraints...so is there anything wrong with my constraints or is there anything wrong with Xcode, and more importantly how to solve this issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could I see the view controller code? The last 2 constraints are system constraints. In 99% of the cases you see them, it's because you are forcing some early layout pass.

Answer (score 0):

Add constraint like this on your `imageview` and `separator view`

[image]

Ex. Add 4 constraint on separator view

1. Leading
2. Top
3. Bottom
4. height

and add 5 constraint on imageview

1. Leading
2. Top
3. Bottom
4. height
5. Aspect ratio with priority 750

you can change priority after adding aspect ratio constraint from size inspector

[image]

after this add this code in viewDidLoad Method

```
  self.table.estimatedRowHeight =  304.0f;
  self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Now all error gone